# Jquery. executes in the Console but will not execute when loaded alongside the HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome-extension

I am working on a chrome extension that will pull an identifier from the HTML into a var and that var is going to be used to fill in a form field.

I have tried to accomplish this with Js. but received the following error in the console:

**"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null"**

```
    <input type="text" name="currId" placeholder="Current ID" id="searchInput">

    someId = "some-thing-nice

    <!--somehow, the line below was throwing the error with the /value. reddit,stack overflow, and random googling confirmed that I was calling an ID that did not exist in the html/ But it definetly did exist. -->
    document.getElementById("searchInput").value = someId;
    var webID = (document.getElementById("searchInput").value = someId;
    console.log(someId);
```

I ended up implementing jquery.

```js
//this Id is polled from another piece of code and passed to the var someID
var someId = "some-thing-nice";
//sets the property with the id searchInput to the var above
$("#searchInput").val(someId);
//this code can be commented out. currSomeId was to be used to validate the copy
var currsomeId = $("#searchInput").val(someId);
window.alert($("#searchInput").val());
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="chrome-extension.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="chrome-extension.js"></script>
  <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <title>Chrome Extension</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="application-heading">someID Extension</h1>
    <hr>
    <p class="program-desc">Some Text</p>
      <!-- this field to be populated -->
    <input type="text" name="currWebID" placeholder="Current someID" id="searchInput">
      <!-- This field to be clicked when the id is populated. -->
    <input type="button" name="submit" id="searchButton" value="Search" role="Search">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

### The end game is to:

1. populate the searchInput field
2. then click searchBtn to be redirected to a url with information about someId

NOTE: oddly enough, the Js executes fine when I manually enter it into the browser console and when I entered it into the StackOverflow Code feature. 
I just can not get the code to run when the page is loaded.

Comment: Basically means that the element doesn't exist at the time you run that code block. If it is inserted later using javascript you need to run it then. If that's all you are trying to do could run it in a `setInterval()` and kill the interval timer when the element does exist. Or look into using Mutation Observer

Comment: awesome thank you. I will give this a-go.